# Versioning multiple subprojects of one root project in Bazaar

Tags: versioning, bazaar

What's currently the best way to version multiple subprojects of one root project in Bazaar?

I'm familiar with `bzr-externals` and `scmproj`. I'm more drawn to `bzr-externals`, since it allows to use builtin commands (I'm using `Bazaar Explorer`), however it seems to lack some features I would like.

My project looks like this:

```
CommonLibrary
ProjectA (uses CommonLibrary)
ProjectB (uses CommonLibrary)
```

However, I would like to be able to store some project-level files (and have them versioned too), because I'm working in Visual Studio (which needs solution file containing information for all its projects).

In almost all cases, I would like both projects to share the same common library.

Also, currently I'm versioning them all under 1 branch - however when I choose any of the above solutions, I will need to split them, but I don't know how (I would like to preserve all history).

What's best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to split your branch, look at the bazaar `split` command. It does the following: Split a subdirectory of a tree into a separate tree.

I also mainly use bzr-externals because it uses the builtin commands.